# Open file in archive 7z to read in Powershell

Tags: powershell, 7zip

I need to open log file in 7z archive containing huge backup file and log file. I need to confirm successful backup by read last few lines of log file.
I've found solution how to do this with zip file:

```
 Add-Type -assembly "system.io.compression.filesystem"
$zip = [io.compression.zipfile]::OpenRead("C:\Users\USER\Documents\Documents.zip")
$file = $zip.Entries | where-object { $_.Name -eq "backup.log"}
$stream = $file.Open() 


$text = Get-Content $file -tail 5
$text

#$reader.Close()
$stream.Close()
$zip.Dispose()
```

How to do the same thing with 7zip archive?

Answer (score 0):

It should take just using the 7z command line tool and passing it the proper arguments,
https://superuser.com/questions/321829/extract-a-certain-file-from-an-archive-with-7-zip-from-the-command-line  has some details on that. Follow the instructions there to utilize the 7z cmd line tool to extract that log from the archive, then use the same structure you have right now to have it parsed.

https://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/index.htm has the details on how to utilize the 7z command line tool.

In your case, the 7z part of this should be something like:

```
$PathtoExecutable\7z.exe e C:\Users\USER\Documents\Documents.7z -oC:\users\user\temp\ backup.log
```

Just replace that PathtoExecutable with the actual path to 7z on your machine, and do the same with the other paths as per the 7z documentation. Then you'll get the .log file in whatever directory you specify as your output directory, after which you should be good to parse it with Get-Content.

Comment: Ok. Its works for static defined path, but how to insert path to file from array or text file where every path is given line by line?